# I want to join balls together

Tags: css, react-native

I have these balls that I want to join together. They should like stick together.

Code for the orange squares.

```
style={{
     backgroundColor: 'orange',
     display: 'flex',
     borderRadius: width
}}
```

Code for the pink area.

```
bubbleViewWrapper: {
   flexWrap: 'wrap',
   backgroundColor: 'pink',
},
```

refer to image below as stack overflow doesn't allow me upload image

what does it look right now
https://ibb.co/T8L56ZF

What I want
https://ibb.co/5R4hLCV

Html structure

```
<ScrollView
                horizontal={true}
                contentContainerStyle={Style.contentContainerStyle}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            >
                <View style={Style.bubbleViewWrapper}>
                    {/ {BubbleStore.map((item, index) => { /}
                    {store.map((item, index) => {
```

More detailed version of Css

```
 contentContainerStyle: {
    height: CONTAINER_SIZE,
    padding: wp(2),
    paddingHorizontal: wp(4),
    // backgroundColor: 'yellow'
},
bubbleViewWrapper: {
    width: 'auto',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
},
circle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borde
```

I have tried `flex: wrap` and some other properties but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You should give more detail like html as well since we don'T know the structure it is built on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.